# How to use additional dimension : direct sessions to the google studio

Tags: session, google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

In google analytics I can add additional dimension which is named: Direct Sessions which gives two values : yes and no. The problem is that when im making reports in google studio i dont have this kind of dimension.

Maybe there is possible to add this dimension manually?

T.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a custom dimension in GA it is available in Google Data Studio (I assume that is what you mean by "Google Studio").

> Currently the Google Analytics connector only provides access to data
>   available in custom reports. It does not provide access to
>   multi-channel funnels or real-time data. However, custom dimensions
>   and metrics are available in Data Studio.

You can select it like any other dimension (use the search feature and look for the name you gave to your dimension in the GA property settings).

[Source](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370352?hl=en)

Comment: Hi! Eike thanks for answer. Situation is a little bit difrent. In google analytics i can filter my data using additional dimension named: Direct Sessions. The problem is that in Google Data Studio there isnt such type of dimension. In now im trying to find the best way how to filter my data in GDS with this dimension. I was thinking about doing it by segmentation but i cant chose "direct sessions" filter both in GA and GDS when im using segmentation. I try to make custom dimension which will be copy of  google dimension Direct Sessions but i failed